# JSON.parse get value

Tags: json, angular, api

I'm trying to retrieve a specific value for a given key. My JSON object looks like this directly taken from the console.

```
0
:
{mail: "testmail@hotmail.com", location: "England", about: "Rockstar", phoneNr: "1233425"}
```

My angular code that retrieves the response and prints it

```
getProfile(){
        const obs = new Subject<Users[]>();
        this.http.post('http://localhost/shareVideoAppPHP/sharevideoapp-backend/readProfile.php', "1", {headers: this.headers})
        .subscribe((message) => { //Function data
            const response = JSON.parse(message.text());
            obs.next(response);
            console.log("Mesage------->", response);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("Error from server!", error);
        });
    }
```

Thinks I've tried

```
response.location
response["location"]
message["location"]
message.location
```

All of them give the following print: `Mesage-------> undefined` except the last one which gives an error `Property 'location' doesn't exist on type Response`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your reponse is an array. You can see that in your log, with the `0` index.

Try doing a

```
console.log(response[0]['location']);
console.log(response[0].location);
```

Comment: Yes thanks, this worked with some modification. Final code was 
 `response.profile[0].location`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to parse the JSON. First of all, you find out the values get from **message** variable. If the JSON values get from the message is the one you desire, then you can use **message.location** to retrieve it.